# How to submit a flask form to a list?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have a flask form that I am submitting. When I submit the form I am trying to post the data to a list as follows:

```
submittedWords=[]
for v in request.form.items():
    submittedWords.append(v)
```

This give mt he following:

```
[('w1', 'first'), ('w2', 'second'), ('w5', 'third'), ('w7', 'fourth'), ('w4', ''), ('w6', ''), ('w3', '')]
```

Where **w1,w2,w3....** is the input name and **first,second,third...** is the data entered/submitted.

Is this tuples inside a list?

Is there a way to just output the 'data' section such as

```
['first','second','third','fourth','','','']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a dict not declared like lookup = {"cat": 1, "dog": 2} ? Not sure how its the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `items` does; it iterates through the dictionary in the form of (key, value) pairs.

If you just want the values, iterate through those:

```
for v in request.form.values():
```

Comment: Perfect. I actaully tried this first and it didn't wok as I must have had an error somewhere else in my code at the time. Just tried it again 2 hours later thanks to you and it worked! WIll mark as correct when it lets me.

Comment: Do you consider this a duplicate? I cannot post any more due to this and I don't think its correct.